# coldfusion bind failed when using jquery's modal

Tags: jquery, coldfusion, jquery-ui-dialog, cfform

Hi i have a cfoutput to loop a query and i'm using dynamic variables to display the layout in client's side, every works fine except for the binding that only works when i'm not using jquery's modal.

there's my coldfusion code

```
<cfoutput query = "RSSelect.rs">
<div id="editar_#idu_programa_detalle#" title="Editar">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="right" valign="middle">Estado:</td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">
            <cfselect 
                title="id_Estado" 
                selected="#RSSelect.RS.idu_estado_salida#" 
                id="idu_estado_salida_#idu_programa_detalle#" 
                name="idu_estado_salida_#idu_programa_detalle#" 
                query="RSEstados.RS" 
                display="nb_Estado" 
                value="id_Estado" 
                queryPosition="below" 
                style="width:200px" 
                required="yes" 
                message="El estado es requerido" 
            >
                <option value="0" >Seleccione estado  </option>
            </cfselect>&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle">Ciudad:
            <cfselect 
                title="Seleccione ciudad" 
                selected="#RSSelect.RS.idu_ciudad_salida#" 
                name="idu_ciudad_salida_#idu_programa_detalle#" 
                id="idu_ciudad_salida_#idu_programa_detalle#" 
                bind="cfc:#Application.CfcPath#.solicitudes_cm_uo.obtenerCiudades({idu_estado_salida_#idu_programa_detalle#@change})" 
                bindonload="yes"  
                value="id_Ciudad" 
                display="nb_Ciudad" 
                queryPosition="below"  
                style="width:200px" 
                required="yes" 
                message="El campo ciudad no debe de quedar vacio"
            >
            </cfselect>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</cfoutput>
```

and jquery code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <cfoutput query = "RSSelect.rs">
        <script>
            $(function()
            {
                $( "##editar_#idu_programa_detalle#" ).dialog(
                {
                    modal:true,
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height:999,
                    width:999,
                    buttons:
                    {
                        "Editar": function()
                        {
                            alert('se edito correctamente');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        },
                        "Cancelar": function()
                        {
                            alert('se cancelo correctamente');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        </cfoutput>
```

I'd apreciate your help.

I tried using showmodaldialog as well but it only works on IE

any other options using a modal dialog would be ok.

Comment: It would help if you showed the HTML ColdFusion generates.

Comment: Which browser developer tool are you using to troubleshoot this?

Comment: if you know jQuery, I'd highly recommend not using `cfselect` or `cfform`.

Comment: I need cfselect and cfform to do the binding, and I'm new on both jquery and coldfusion.

Comment: You _don't_ need cfselect and cfform to do the binding - you can do it with jQuery, and doing it with jQuery will give you significantly more control over it, and make it far less likely to conflict. (Learning jQuery is also a more useful skill, and something there are a greater number of people able to help debug issues with.)

Comment: Sorry for asking again but i dont have internet access on my work but how i populate another select after the first one changes i'm using coldfusion binding to call a function but i dont know how to do that using jquery.

Comment: Posting on Stackoverflow without internet access is quite a neat trick.

Comment: I don't i used my mobile as a modem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically a call a function to open the modal dialog.

Well i think I coded too much but here it is =).

```
<script language="javascript">
function OpenPop(idu_programa,idu_programa_detalle)
{
    var x = false;
    //alert('algo');
    x = showModalDialog('pop_editar_detalle_supervision.cfm?idu_programa='+idu_programa+'&idu_programa_detalle='+idu_programa_detalle,'dialogHeight:1000px;dialogWidth:1000px;');
    if (typeof x == 'undefined')
    {
        alert('Edicion cancelada');
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('idu_programa_detalle_pop').value = idu_programa_detalle
        document.getElementById('idu_estado_salida_pop').value = x[0];
        document.getElementById('idu_ciudad_salida_pop').value = x[1];
        document.getElementById('fec_salida_pop').value = x[2];
        document.getElementById('opc_meridiano_salida_pop').value = x[3];
        document.getElementById('fec_supervision_inicial_pop').value = x[4];
        document.getElementById('fec_supervision_final_pop').value = x[5];
        document.getElementById('opc_meridiano_supervision_inicio_pop').value = x[6];
        document.getElementById('form1').submit();
    }       
}
</script>
```

Then I returned the values on an array then i put the values on hidden inputs to call them after submit

Here is the modal javascript code that returns the array.

```
<script language="javascript">
function Editar()
{
    var valoresDevueltos = new Array();
    valoresDevueltos[0] = document.getElementById('idu_estado_salida').value;
    valoresDevueltos[1] = document.getElementById('idu_ciudad_salida').value;
    valoresDevueltos[2] = document.getElementById('fec_salida').value;
    if(document.getElementById('amSalida').checked)
    {
        valoresDevueltos[3] = document.getElementById('amSalida').value;
    }
    else
    {
        valoresDevueltos[3] = document.getElementById('pmSalida').value;
    }
    valoresDevueltos[4] = document.getElementById('fec_supervision_inicial').value;
    valoresDevueltos[5] = document.getElementById('fec_supervision_final').value;
    //Checking which radioButton is checked
    if(document.getElementById('amSupervision').checked)
    {
        valoresDevueltos[6] = document.getElementById('amSupervision').value;
    }
    else
    {
        valoresDevueltos[6] = document.getElementById('pmSupervision').value;
    }
    window.returnValue = valoresDevueltos;
    window.close();
}
</script>
```

Hope it is clear enough if not let me know to improve my answer thank you for your patience =)

Answer (score 2):

It appears as though your jQuery code is contained within the header of your HTML document. Of course your CFML is contained within the body of your HTML document. When using jQuery you need to be careful that you only access items in the DOM when they are available. You can avert some of these issues by wrapping your jQuery code within the `$(document).ready()` function. Something like this...

```
<cfoutput query = "RSSelect.rs">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $( "##editar_#idu_programa_detalle#" ).dialog(
            {
                modal:true,
                autoOpen: false,
                height:999,
                width:999,
                buttons:
                {
                    "Editar": function()
                    {
                        alert('se edito correctamente');
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    },
                    "Cancelar": function()
                    {
                        alert('se cancelo correctamente');
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</cfoutput>
```

[Here is the documentation on the ready() function.](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

---

*Initial issue that has since been corrected in the question*

I'm not sure if this is the issue but your `<div>` tags are not positioned correctly. The opening `<div>` tag is within the `<cfoutput>` block...

```
<cfoutput query = "RSSelect.rs">
<div id="editar_#idu_programa_detalle#" title="Editar">
```

but the closing tag is after the `</cfoutput>` and thus outside the loop...

```
</cfoutput>
</div>
```

The closing `</div>` tag should be *within* the `cfoutput` block, so that each opened div is also closed...

```
</div>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: I cut the code to focus on the issue, but in the original code the closing </div> code is inside the </cfoutput>, the problem is that binds fail when using jquery's modal, but when I comment the jquery code it works, but i need the modal.

Comment: Where is your jQuery code in relation to your ColdFusion output code? You may need to wrap all of your jQuery functions within `$(document).ready()` to make sure the items that you are referencing exist in the DOM.

Comment: _binds fail when using jquery's modal_ What does that mean? Are you getting an error? The selects don't populate with data? We need more details. Check your javascript console for errors in your browser. What do you see?

Comment: it appears alerts saying. bind failed element not found: idu_estado_salida_6

bind failed element not found: idu_estado_salida_7

bind failed element not found: idu_estado_salida_8 and so on

Comment: Since the code that you posted here is not the actual code that is failing it is hard to figure out the problem. As Tomalak suggested shortly after you asked this question you will need to examine the generated output on the client machine (view source code) to see what the issue is. If your `cfselect` code is working without jQuery then I would suggest adding the jQuery code back in to your code one    item at a time until you find what breaks the other code. For example, take your working code and then simply add the jQuery includes. Does your code break? If not, then try more and test. Etc.

Comment: Thanks i found another way to solve it. I will post it shortly.